# Foundation 6 tooltip click event in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I've been trying to make something happen when clicking the tooltip in Foundation 6.
Everything seem to work fine when I test my work on a desktop browser (or any browser which is not iOS Safari).

In Safari for iOS the tooltip does not respond, as if no click is made.

```
$(document).foundation();

$(".tooltip").off();
$(".tooltip").click(()=>{
  alert("!");
});
```

I have my code here:  https://codepen.io/Nirtz89/pen/MVbxpo

Thanks!

Comment: Please use the `zurb-foundation` tags next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I've found a solution.

```
$("body").on("touchstart", ".tooltip", function () {
    // Code for tooltip press here
});
```

This works perfectly.